# Echo command not working inside shell script on git bash for Windows

Tags: windows, bash, git, echo, git-bash

Folks, I am quite unfamiliar with git/bash/shell scripting, so please forgive the noobness in this question. I have made a lot of effort to find the answer on SO, on the web and through trial and error but it hasn't worked.

I am using **git bash** on **Windows 10**. My question is: I am able to successfully use the `echo` command at the git bash command prompt, but it doesn't work inside a shell script I have written (the purpose of the shell script is to execute a few git commands in succession).

So, this works at the command prompt:

```
echo "This is a test"
```

But if I make a shell script named script.sh with the following contents:

```
echo "Running a few git commands in batch"
git status
git add .
git commit -m "Batch publishing changes"
git push
```

and enter `. script.sh` at the command prompt then I don't see the output of the `echo "Running a few git commands in batch"` command even though the later (git) commands work alright. What gives?

Comment: Can't be. Prove it with a screenshot, but do a `set -x` before exectuting `. script.sh`. In theory the only explanation - if you really see this behaviour - which I could imagine, is, that the first line of your script has a trailing carriage return. This is something you could check for the safe side.

Comment: @user1934428 I reopened everything to try your suggestion and somehow now it works. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  Even without doing the `set -x`. I don't know what was amiss and I'm feeling a little sheepish now but I appreciate your informative answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i would check the git bash is added to your `PATH` environment variable, the script would be looking for the `echo` command, and this cannot be found and then the command cannot run.

Comment: My issue was caused by something else apparently, but this is helpful to know. Thanks.